# How do I prevent NIntegrate::inumr errors within other functions?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, interpolation

I believe this question is best illustrated with a simple example. If I run

```
FunctionInterpolation[NIntegrate[a + b, {a, 0, 1}], {b, 0, 1}]
```

I get errors of the form

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand a+b has evaluated to non-numerical values for all 
sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.
```

So I guess Mathematica is evaluating the expression before plugging in values and trying to interpolate it. Admittedly the code does yield apparently correct results, so I could just turn off the error message and be done with it, but I'd like to address the root cause if possible. Is there some more correct way to do what I'm trying to do that would not spit out an error message in the first place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could define a function which is evaluated only when its argument is numeric :

```
int[b_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a + b, {a, 0, 1}]

FunctionInterpolation[int[b], {b, 0, 1}]
```

[Here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502) you can find a Wolfram support article explaining why `NumericQ` helps here and how to use it, in detail.

Comment: Ah, good idea, that could work. It'd be nice to avoid having to define a separate function, though.

Comment: There is an article here http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820 that helps explain why you should use NumericQ.

Comment: Sadly the link to the aforementioned link is now broken.

Comment: @Corvus A quick search gives [http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502), possibly the same article.