# How to numerically integrate this integral?

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I want to integrate a function (spherical coordinates):

$$\int _0^{2 \pi }\int _0^{\pi }\frac{r^2 \sin (\theta ) e^{-\lambda  \sqrt{\rho ^2+r^2-2 \rho  r \cos (\theta )}-2 r}}{\pi  \epsilon  \sqrt{\rho ^2+r^2-2 \rho  r \cos (\theta )}}d\theta d\rho , ϵ=78.36, λ=0.548881$$

```
ϵ=78.36
λ=0.548881    
funcin = 
  1/(ϵ*π)*Exp[-(2*r + λ*Sqrt[r^2 + ρ^2 - 
    2*r*ρ*Cos[θ]])]*r^2*Sin[θ]*1/Sqrt[ρ^2 + r^2 - 2*r*ρ*Cos[θ]]
intfuncing = Integrate[funcin, {r, 0, Infinity}, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0,2 π}]
```

If I use analytic calculation (`Integrate`), an integral over r is left, which must be numerically evaluated, e.g., by using `N[intfuncing]` for specific ρ. For example I can write:

```
 Do[ρ = 0.1 + (i - 1)*0.05; int[[i]] = N[intfuncing], {i, 60}]
```

to calculate the integral at 60 points. But I get an error by that:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

If I try to evaluate the integral numerically with `NIntegrate`, I get:

> the integral ... evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{∞, 0.}, {0, 3.14159}, {0, 6.28319}}.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is what I did, but the numerical integration gave the error with the convergence...

Comment: see here for the second error http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/how-do-i-prevent-nintegrateinumr-errors-within-other-functions, but really but really dont waste time with that if you can do it partially analytically

Comment: note the original formulation actually works (I cant reproduce that error). Anyway its worth a note that its horrifically slow because `N[Integrate[..]]` re tries the analytic approach before evaluating numerically (x60...).  Anybondy know the incantation to extract the arguments from an `Integrate` expression without evaluating it? (besides cut-paste! )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the whole thing analytically:

```
(*ϵ=78.36;
λ=0.548881;*)
Clear[ϵ, λ];
funcin = 1/(ϵ * π) *
   Exp[-(2*r + λ * Sqrt[r^2 + ρ^2 - 2*r*ρ * Cos[θ]])] * r^2 * Sin[θ] *
    1 / Sqrt[ρ^2 + r^2 - 2*r*ρ * Cos[θ]];
intfuncinang = Assuming[r > 0 && ρ > 0 && ϵ > 0 && λ > 0,
  Integrate[funcin, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
  ]
(*
  -((2 E^(-2 r) (E^(-λ (r + ρ)) - E^(-λ Abs[r - ρ])) r)/(ϵ λ ρ))
*)

Assuming[ρ > 0 && ϵ > 0 && λ > 0,
  Integrate[intfuncinang, {r, 0, ρ}] + Integrate[intfuncinang, {r, ρ, Infinity}]
  ] // Simplify
(*
   (4 E^(-2 (1 + λ) ρ) (4 E^((2 + λ) ρ) + E^(2 λ ρ) (-4 + (-4 + λ^2) ρ))) /
     (ϵ (-4 + λ^2)^2 ρ)
*)
```

Comment: Good idea to separate the integration space, works out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the integrals over the angular variables analytically; the result will be a function of `r, ρ` :

```
intth = 2 Pi Integrate[funcin, θ];
integ[ρ_] = (intth /. θ -> Pi) - (intth /. θ -> 0) ;

output = Table[{ρ, NIntegrate[integ[ρ], {r, 0, Infinity}]}, {ρ, 0.1, 3,0.05}] ;

ListLinePlot[output]
```

[image: plot]