# Sum with IntegerQ does not converge

Tags: summation, expression-test

Why does *Mathematica* return:

> ```
> Sum::div: Sum does not converge. >>
> ```

when I input:

```
Sum[Boole[!IntegerQ[x]], {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

The sum is obviously $0$.

Comment: What seems to happen is that `!IntegerQ[x]` gets evaluated right away to True, this is before the sum takes hold. Hence the result becomes `Boole[True]` which is `1` and the whole sum becomes just `Sum[1, {x, 1, Infinity}]` which diverges. You can see this more clearly like this: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh64h.png) need to find a way to tell M to delay this evaluation.

Comment: what do you get for a finite sum?

Comment: The sum is 0 for any arbitrarily large finite value, but the infinite sum doesn't converge. I'm not sure why it evaluates it to true if I'm summing over natural numbers.

Comment: You can also see this more clearly like this `Sum[Boole[Not[IntegerQ[x]]], {x, 1, k}]` which gives `k`. So let `k` to any value, say Infinity, and you see the problem. It is all due to evaluation of `!IntegerQ[x]` before the sum even starts. Since you are summing to Infinity, I am not sure how else M will handle this, as the function needs to be analytical for M to figure the sum.

Comment: So how do I make Mathematica evaluate the sum correctly?

Comment: Is this more than a curiosity?  Can you show a real problem where this is an issue?   One thing to try is feeding `Sum[]` a function using `/;NumericQ` (no mathematica at the moment or id try it..)

Comment: No, I'm new to mathematica and just trying to get my head around it. I'll try that.

Comment: take a look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/how-do-i-prevent-nintegrateinumr-errors-within-other-functions

Comment: `Sum[Boole[!x \[Element] Integers],{x,1,Infinity}]` also is reported to not converge, despite not using the problematic `IntegerQ` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found something that works:

```
 Sum[Boole[! (IntegerPart[x] == x)], {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

> 0

This other thing I suggested does not work:

```
 intq[x_?NumericQ] := IntegerQ[x];
 Sum[Boole[! intq[x]], {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

(* remains unevaluated *)

It could be `Sum` is smart enough to first simplify assuming integers:

```
 Simplify[ Boole[(! IntegerPart[x] == x)] , Element[x, Integers]]
 Simplify[ Boole[! intq[x]] , Element[x, Integers]]
```

> 0
>
> Boole[! intq[x]]

Comment: One could also use a representation using `Mod[]`: `Sum[Boole[Mod[x, 1] != 0], {x, 1, Infinity}]`

Answer (score 7):

Before `x` is a assigned a value its `Head` is `Symbol`. Thus `IntegerQ[x]` yields `False`.

That means `Boole[!IntegerQ[x]]` will be simplified to 1 and the sum will not converge. This can be seen with Trace.

Any integer value as upper bound of the sum will however yield 0 as expected.

```
Sum[Boole[! IntegerQ[x]], {x, 1, 100}]
```

Out:

```
0
```

As far as I understand the behaviour of `Sum` in thise case it will evalute the exrpession symbolicaly in case of an infinite sum and numericaly in case of a finite sum.

edit: sorry didn't notice the comments