# Using OddQ and EvenQ in piecewise functions: Buggy?

Tags: piecewise, expression-test

I was trying to evaluate a sum over a piecewise function, not unlike [this example](https://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/DiscreteCalculus/FindTheSumOfAPiecewiseSequence.html).  However, my piecewise function needed to be defined differently for even and odd `k`.  This is a simpler version of my function, just so we can all agree that the sum exists:

```
f[k_]:=Piecewise[{{1, k==0}, {x^k/k!, OddQ[k]}, {x^k/k!, EvenQ[k]}}]
```

(I keep `x` and `k` undefined throughout.  I know that this could be simplified, but this is just for the purposes of having a minimal working example.)

If, for example, I evaluate `f[3]`, I get `x^3/6`, as expected.  Or if I do

```
Sum[f[k], {k,0,5}]
```

I get the expected answer -- a nice little sum of terms involving powers of `x`.  I can also do

```
Sum[x^k/k!, {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

And get `E^x`, as expected.

But if I evaluate

```
Sum[f[k], {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

I get `1`.  And, when I evaluate `f[k]`, I get

```
Piecewise[{{1, k == 0}}, 0]
```

And yet, it still knows that `f[k]` is not just this when I pass an actual integer (e.g., `3`), or ask for a finite `Sum`; it actually does remember more about `f` than these results suggest.

What is going on?

## Edit

As J.M. pointed out in the comments, apparently `OddQ` and `EvenQ` evaluate on a symbol, before it is known whether it represents an integer -- never mind an even or odd one.  The solution (adding `IntegerPart`) to the question george2079 linked does not help.  But J.M. did suggest a workaround: change `OddQ[k]` to `Mod[k,2]==1`, and `EvenQ[k]` to `Mod[k,2]==0`.  (I maintain that mathematica should be a little more clever about when it evaluates things, rather than silently given the right answer to a question I didn't mean to ask.  But I guess it's legacy code by now.)

Comment: possible dup http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45998/2079

Comment: In brief: `EvenQ[]` and `OddQ[]` return `False` for any input that is manifestly not an integer. Use checks based on `Mod[]` instead.

Comment: Thanks J.M.  That works.  If you'd care to make that an answer, I'd be happy to accept.  Though I'm really unhappy with mathematica for quiet quirks like this.  Back to pencil and paper for me, I guess...

Comment: Someone else could expand on this, I guess: `*Q[]` functions for testing expressions are only ever intended to return `True` or `False`. Contrast this with functions like `Equal[]` or `Positive[]`, that can remain inert until its arguments become a form these functions can act on.

Comment: @Mike I have encountered the same problem ... that OddQ[x] returns False, without even knowing whether x is odd or not. I find it most 'unnatural', and most un-Mathematica like, and wish it were otherwise.

Comment: You can also use `Divisible`.

Comment: @wolfies: The documentation states that `OddQ[expr]` returns `True` only if `expr` is an odd integer.

Comment: @Berg We use _Mathematica_ because we are interested in a world that does not simply consist of numerics, but rather one of symbols that may or may not be positive, even, odd etc. `Positive[x]` does NOT return False, because it understands that x might be positive, so it returns `Positive[x]`, unless we tell it something more about `x`. The same symbolic behaviour would be desirable for the ___Q funcs, such as `EvenQ`, `OddQ` etc ... which currently are basically numeric functions, and which, in my view, operate in a manner that appears inconsistent with the symbolic underpinnings of Mma.

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment, @wolfies, the `*Q[]` functions are not intended to remain inert; they must return either `True` or `False`. Granted, a version of `OddQ[]`/`EvenQ[]` that remains inert for ambiguous arguments would be useful…

Comment: @wolfies: I was merely stating that `OddQ` behaves as documented. In fact, there is even an example in the documentation, which shows that `OddQ[x]` gives `False` for non-numeric `x`. This design decision has the advantage that functions of the form `*Q` always return boolean values and `If` statements evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by J.M., the solution is to use `Mod`:

```
f[k_] := Piecewise[{{1, k==0}, {x^k/k!, Mod[k, 2]==1}, {x^k/k!, Mod[k, 2]==0}}]
```

This returns the expected values for both

```
Sum[f[k], {k,0,5}]
```

and for

```
Sum[f[k], {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

As an interface-design issue, the choice to make `*Q` functions return a value even for generic symbols seems like a very poor and inconsistent one.  But at least now I know to be wary...

Answer (score 1):

It has already been pointed out that the problem originates from the fact that `OddQ[x]` evaluates to `False` if `x` is not a numerical value. Note that it is not hard to define test function that returns unevaluated for symbolic arguments:

```
CEvenQ[n_Integer] := EvenQ[n]
COddQ[n_Integer] := OddQ[n]
```

Now, `COddQ[2]` gives `False` and `COddQ[x]` is returned unevaluated. So,

```
f[k_] := Piecewise[{{1, k == 0}, {x^k/k!, COddQ[k]}, {x^k/k!,CEvenQ[k]}}]
Sum[f[k], {k, 0, 4}]
Sum[f[k], {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives the same finite sum as before and returns the second, infinite, sum unevaluated.

It is also possible to add some smartness to this function:

```
CEvenQ[z_Integer x_] := EvenQ[z] || CEvenQ[x]
```

gives `True` if any expression `x` is multiplied by an even integer. (Whether this rule is desirable depends, of course, on assumptions about the expressions handed to `CEvenQ`.)

Comment: The second (infinite) sum should return `E^x`.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons, I had difficulty getting the above solutions to work out. What worked for me was to use the Mod function with multiplication, as in:

```
f[k_]:=(1-Mod[k,2]) EvenFunc[k] + Mod[k,2] OddFunc[k]
```

Kinda hacky but got the job done.