# Mod[k, 2] == 0 versus EvenQ[k]

Tags: function-construction, core-language

I'm having some trouble with

```
Mod[k, 2] == 0
```

versus

```
EvenQ[k]
```

They are sometimes yielding different results when given the same input.

A function I'm attempting to define:

```
sinmultipletheta[n_] := 
  ComplexExpand[Im[(Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])^n]] /.
    {Cos[θ]^k_ -> 
      If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, 
        (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^(k/2), 
        (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^((k - 1)/2) Cos[θ]]} // Expand
```

This yields the correct answer. For example,

```
sinmultipletheta[9]
```

> ```
> 9 Sin[θ] - 120 Sin[θ]^3 + 432 Sin[θ]^5 - 576 Sin[θ]^7 + 256 Sin[θ]^9
> ```

When I replace `Mod[k, 2] == 0` above with `EvenQ[k]`, that is if I define

```
sinmultipletheta[n_] := 
  ComplexExpand[
    Im[(Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])^n]] /. 
      {Cos[θ]^k_ -> 
        If[EvenQ[k], 
          (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^(k/2), 
          (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^((k - 1)/2) Cos[θ]]} // Expand
```

then

```
sinmultipletheta[9]
```

> ```
> Sin[θ]^9 + 9 Cos[θ] Sin[θ] Sqrt[1 - Sin[θ]^2] - 
>     111 Cos[θ] Sin[θ]^3 Sqrt[1 - Sin[θ]^2] + 
>     321 Cos[θ] Sin[θ]^5 Sqrt[1 - Sin[θ]^2] - 
>     255 Cos[θ] Sin[θ]^7 Sqrt[1 - Sin[θ]^2]
> ```

In this case, it seems my conditional statement is always evaluated as though it were false.

Any insight?

Comment: Check the documentation for EvenQ: "`EvenQ[expr]` returns `False` unless `expr` is manifestly an even integer (i.e. has head `Integer`, and is even)". This is different from `Mod` and `Divisible`.

Comment: "An important feature of all the Wolfram Language property-testing functions whose names end in Q is that they always return False if they cannot determine whether the expression you give has a particular property. "

Comment: Related: [(109115)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109115/using-oddq-and-evenq-in-piecewise-functions-buggy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[sinmultipletheta]

sinmultipletheta[n_] := 
 ComplexExpand[
    Im[(Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])^n]] /. {Cos[θ]^k_ -> 
     If[Mod[k, 2] == 
       0, (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^(k/
         2), (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^((k - 1)/2) Cos[θ]]} // Expand

expr1 = sinmultipletheta[9]

(*  9 Sin[θ] - 120 Sin[θ]^3 + 432 Sin[θ]^5 - 
 576 Sin[θ]^7 + 256 Sin[θ]^9  *)

expr2 = sinmultipletheta[n]

(*  Sin[n Arg[Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ]]]  *)

Clear[sinmultipletheta]
```

Use [RuleDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) to keep the RHS of the rule from being evaluated until the function is called.

```
sinmultipletheta[n_] := 
 ComplexExpand[
    Im[(Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])^n]] /. {Cos[θ]^k_ :> 
     If[EvenQ[k], (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^(k/
         2), (1 - Sin[θ]^2)^((k - 1)/2) Cos[θ]]} // Expand

expr3 = sinmultipletheta[9]

(*  9 Sin[θ] - 120 Sin[θ]^3 + 432 Sin[θ]^5 - 
 576 Sin[θ]^7 + 256 Sin[θ]^9  *)

expr4 = sinmultipletheta[n]

(*  Sin[n Arg[Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ]]]  *)

expr1 == expr3

(*  True  *)

expr2 == expr4

(*  True  *)
```